# Possible to change the dialog right position in the style to the new value in jquery?

Tags: jquery, dialog

Just wandering will it be possible to change the dialog right position in the style to the new value in jquery?

Example:

I have the following dialog loaded on the page with the following set of style value:

```
<dialog class="mdl-dialog test" style="padding:0px;position:absolute;top:340px;right:183px;margin-right:0">
</dialog >
```

Any way that I can change the dialog right position in the style to the new value in jquery as following :

```
<dialog class="mdl-dialog test" style="padding:0px;position:absolute;top:340px;right:1403px;margin-right:0">
</dialog >
```

Comment: Wow, that's a *lot* of [**questions you've asked**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/52745/jin-yong?tab=questions) where you haven't accepted an answer. Are you sure none of those questions have been resolved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$('.mdl-dialog').css('right', '1403px')` should do it for you. The css function alters the style attribute on the selected elements.